# Dialog box showing ajax success response disappears immediately

Tags: codeigniter, jquery

I am Uploading both data and files in one form using Ajax in Codigniter and displaying the ajax success response in a dialog box, but the dialog box disappears immediately, not showing the result for few minutes.. Here is the code..

```
$(function(){
$("#pushform").submit(function(){
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
$.ajax({
    url:'<?=base_url()?>addpush',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
    document.getElementById('ajaxresult').innerHTML=response;
        $('#result').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            height: 300,
            width:500,
            modal: true,
            duration: 5000
        });
    $('#dialogalert').hide();
    $('#sample').load("<?=base_url()?>pushnotify");
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
return false;
});
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Did u check this line: `$('#dialogalert').hide();` May be that's the culprit!!!

Comment: i check it is not the culprit,but the dialog box is disappearing as soon as i click on the submit button